# corrupt .bashrc: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: bash, unix

I was customizing my local environment on CentOS server.
During the debugging process, I figured out that I did not provide `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. So I modified .bashrc file by adding `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path`. That is when all commands started giving an error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

From the log, I suspect that there was a typo in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. However, rewriting both `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` to their global destinations on the server did not give me anything.

```
~$ nano .bash_profile 
~$ nano .bashrc 
~$ source .bashrc 
~$ $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
bash: :/path/to/my/folder/tools/lib: No such file or directory
~$ nano .bashrc 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
~$ nano .bashrc 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
~$ cat .bashrc 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Only cd and echo commands worked for me. Obviously, the solutions with `cp` intact .bashrc in my directory did not work either. Now, I am totally lost and do not know, how to recover this situation.

Comment: I suspect you were successful in changing the library path and now all applications that need to find libraries in the standard location -- can't. Undo that change.

Comment: You can probably inspect your `.bashrc` by running `while read -r; do printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"; done < .bashrc`. And you can wipe out the file by running `: > .bashrc`.

Comment: `cd` and `echo` are both built-in, so they work even when you can't run external commands.

Comment: anyhow, yeah -- `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the quick way to get your current session unhorked.

Comment: For future reference, keep the editor to .bashrc open and test in a different window :) (Whether that extra window is a second ssh into the sever, another terminal in gnome, kde, etc., or screen or tmux, doesn't matter - just keep open working shells so you can fix this type of thing easier.)

Comment: ...and btw, if you want to *list* your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`'s current contents, you want `printf '%q\n' "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` or `declare -p LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, not just `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on its own. Even `echo "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`, which is prone to wildly misleading output, is better.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that you have no. Properly restored the variable. Try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''` at your Bash prompt to erase its value in your current session; then external commands like `cat` and `nano` should hopefully work again.

Comment: btw, `printf '%s\n' "$(<.bashrc)"` is another way to list your current `.bashrc` contents without using any external commands.

Comment: ...to be very, *very* clear, though -- `nano` and `cat` aren't failing because the `.bashrc` file is corrupt in a way that stops them from opening it; they're failing because they're external commands and both `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` change how external commands are started. You couldn't open any other file with `nano` while your system is in this state either.

Comment: FWIW, notice that a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` of the form `:/path/to` (notice the extra colon in the bash error message!!) is something very nasty as any program will first look in the current dir for shared libraries and dlopen'ed objects, opening avenues for dll injection, or simply very confusing behavior -- it's hard to see why anyone would want that.

Comment: It turned out that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was corrupted. Rolling it back solved the issue. Thank you everyone for useful suggestions!

Comment: I was in the same situation, I've set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH ` in to .bashrc file, load that file, and then I receive message `Segmentation fault` when running any command (ls, ll, vi, vim, nano...), but after switching to another user, restore .bashrc contents, source file again - my system come back to normal.